I am having trouble getting rid of the whitespace i have inbetween some of my div columns
this is a picture of the issue I am currently coding a website for a client. This is a portfolio website to showcase their photography and im running into an issue with my layout. I have one div as my parent with the class of row on it then i have my picture elements wrapped in divs with the column class. The issue i seem to be running into is that the browser/HTML thinks my divs are bigger than they are and it is creating white space on the bottom of some of the columns. I have found one work around be it requires me to change the height of my images to 16% and have the object-fit set to cover but now the images are cut off and all the same size square. I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction to get my divs to not add so much white space. i will provide my code and an image of the issue below.
  <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/bill-ironstand-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/bill-ironstand-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/bill-ironstand.webp" alt="Portrait of Bill Ironstand">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/christmas-day-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/christmas-day-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/christmas-day.webp" alt="Portrait of a baby on christmas day">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/business-woman-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/business-woman-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/business-woman.webp" alt="Portrait of a business woman">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-3-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-3-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-3.webp" alt="Family Portrait of the Richardsons">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/sydney-boyce-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/sydney-boyce-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/sydney-boyce.webp" alt="Portrait of Syney Boyce">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/yellow-mits-front-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/yellow-mits-front-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/yellow-mits-front.webp" alt="Portrait of man with yellow mits">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/adrielle-aquino-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/adrielle-aquino-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/adrielle-aquino.webp" alt="Portrait of Adrielle Aquino">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/alexa-broen-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/alexa-broen-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/alexa-broen.webp" alt="Portrait of Alexa Broen">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/amie-doucette-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/amie-doucette-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/amie-doucette.webp" alt="Portait of Amie Doucette">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/andrea-klapstein-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/andrea-klapstein-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/andrea-klapstein.webp" alt="Portait of Andrea Klapstein">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/band-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/band-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/band.webp" alt="Portait of a Band">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/bill-ironstand-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/bill-ironstand-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/bill-ironstand.webp" alt="Second portait of Bill Ironstand">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/blazer-woman-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/blazer-woman-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/blazer-woman.webp" alt="Portait of a woman with a blazer">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/blue-suit-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/blue-suit-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/blue-suit-2.webp" alt="Portait of man in blue suit">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/blue-suit-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/blue-suit-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/blue-suit.webp" alt="Close up portait of man in blue suit">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/christmas-fam-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/christmas-fam-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/christmas-fam.webp" alt="Portait of a family on christmas day">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/couple-hug-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/couple-hug-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/couple-hug.webp" alt="Portait of a couple embracing">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/couple-pink-front-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/couple-pink-front-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/couple-pink-front.webp" alt="Portait of a couple">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/curly-hair-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/curly-hair-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/curly-hair.webp" alt="Portait of a woman with curly hair">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/dree-beaudry-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/dree-beaudry-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/dree-beaudry.webp" alt="Portait of Dree Beaudry">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/driver-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/driver-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/driver.webp" alt="Portrait of a Driver">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/evan-oliver-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/evan-oliver-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/evan-oliver.webp" alt="Portrait of Evan Oliver">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/family-portait-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/family-portait-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/family-portait-2.webp" alt="Second Family Portrait">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/family-portait-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/family-portait-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/family-portait.webp" alt="Third Family Portrait">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/henry-deng-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/henry-deng-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/henry-deng.webp" alt="Portrait of Henry Deng">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/hilary-meng-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/hilary-meng-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/hilary-meng-2.webp" alt="Portrait of Hilary Meng">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/hilary-meng-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/hilary-meng-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/hilary-meng.webp" alt="Second portrait of Hilary Meng">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/joel-rf-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/joel-rf-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/joel-rf.webp" alt="Portrait of Joel">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/lisa-bains-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/lisa-bains-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/lisa-bains.webp" alt="Portrait of Lisa Bains">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-dog-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-dog-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/man-dog.webp" alt="Portrait of a man and his dog">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-green-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-green-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/man-green.webp" alt="portrait of a man in a green sweatshirt">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-zip-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-zip-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/man-zip.webp" alt="Portrait of a man in a zip up jacket">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/mayra-chavez-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/mayra-chavez-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/mayra-chavez.webp" alt="Portrait of Mayra Chavez">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-2.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-bumper-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-bumper-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-bumper.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-close-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-close-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-close.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-light-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-light-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-light.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-mask-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-mask-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-mask.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-2.webp" alt="richardson family portrait">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo.webp" alt="richardson family portrait">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-2.webp" alt="portrait of Sydney Senuda">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-md.webp alt=">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/senuda-sydney.webp" alt="portrait of Sydney and Senuda">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-wettasinghe-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-wettasinghe-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/senuda-wettasinghe.webp" alt="portrait of Sydney and Senuda">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/singer-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/singer-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/singer-2.webp" alt="portrait of a singer">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/singer-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/singer-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/singer.webp" alt="portrait of a singer">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/yellow-mits-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/yellow-mits-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/yellow-mits.webp" alt="Portrait of a man with yellow mits">
                </picture>

            </div>

        </div>

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
    max-height: 50%;
}

.column picture {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.column img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 16%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* Media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .column {
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

this is my CSS and HTML currently i have the object-fit:cover and the height:16% this is the way i was able to work around it but it crops the images and makes them all the same size. I want to avoid doing that

I'm not quite clear what the problem is as the picture of the issue doesn't seem to match the verbal description. In the picture, the problem would seem to be that the div/image on the left is taking up a lot more space than is required, vertically, so remaining pictures are in the right hand column but there is space for them in the left. Can you show a mock-up of the desired result? Also put placeholder images into your code so we can see the problem.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp
this is my desired result but yea i didn't properly describe the issue because im not sure whats happening. The divs seem to be making space for images that arent there which in turn is creating a huge block of whitespace between columns

I think your issue comes with the padding value "column class":
.column {
flex: 25%;
max-width: 25%;
padding: 0 4px;
max-height: 50%;}

You are assigning 4 pixels both to left and right padding. (Take into account that when you only provide 2 values, the first one is assigned to both top and bottom padding, and the second one is assigned to both left and right).
For more information, take a look at this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-padding/

Thank you for your response! i took out the padding but that still doesnt fix the issue sadly.

There is also some padding in the .row class, and if you really want to only see images without any space between them you should also add a margin of 0 to the body and remove the margin-top and margin-bottom from the picture and img elements.

yea i have a picture attached of what my issue is. it seems like some divs are making space for images that arent there. the padding between the images is fine however if you look at the picture i attached the issue is a little more clear.

What you are describing, seems to be the behaviour of the min-width attribute (used in your ). Take into account that min-width takes the space, even when the element is empty. (https://medium.com/@soojlee0701/width-min-width-max-width-c9e09ea667ce#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20an%20item,fit%20the%20whole%20screen%20initially.&text=This%20Pen%20is%20owned%20by%20Soojeong%20on%20CodePen.,-See%20more%20by)

Okay, now that I’m clear on what the problem is, it’s being caused by this line of code. If you remove it you will see the difference straight away.
.column img {
  height: 16%;
}

It doesn’t make sense to set a height for the images in your intended layout. Don’t you want to use a variety of images with different aspect ratios?
I would use the oft-neglected multiple columns feature of CSS, rather than flex, for this particular layout.


const a = []
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
  const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 200
  a.push(`<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/${id}/300/${height}">`)
}
document.body.innerHTML = a.join('')
body {
  margin: 1em;
  column-width: 300px;
  gap: 1em;
  background: #555;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}




I appreciate your comment, however i think the way i described the problem was wrong. the padding is fine inbetween the pictures, however a few of my column divs have a massive block of whitespace if you click the picture i attached you can see what im trying to describe.

I have looked at this problem again, and updated my answer.

yes thank you, yea i want to use different aspect ratios, like i said in the post that was a small work around i found to work however its not what the client or myself wants for the layout but ill try your code here and look into using the multiple columns feature. thank you for taking time to help me out and answer my question.
